# Как перевести двумерный массив (массив массивов) в CSV формат и вернуть строку?

Tags: javascript, массивы, csv

Например у нас есть массив:

```
const arr = [[1, 2], ['a', 'b']]
```

нужно вернуть строку в формате CSV:

```
'1,2\na,b' // примерно вот так
```

Как это реализовать?

Comment: Вы задали в общей сумме 8 вопросов и на каждый получили ответ, но не приняли ответ как решение (отметили галочкой) **не по одному из них**. Отметьте те ответы, которые Вам помогли "как решения", что бы сообщество было заинтересовано продолжать Вам помогать.

Comment: Пожалуйста, более вдумчиво относитесь к меткам. Если лепить метку "массив" на каждый вопрос, в котором есть код с использованием массивов, то она будет на каждом втором вопросе. То же относится и к метке "алгоритм"

Comment: @Xander метки именно для этого и сделаны. В данном случае это вопрос касающийся массивов, где автор спрашивает о том как трансформировать данный массив что бы получить требуемый ему результат, т.е реализовать алгоритм

Comment: @Vasily Вопрос автора никак не касается массивов. Данная метка нужна для вопросов о нюансах использования и реализации массивов. То, что исходные данные в массиве лежат - не повод использовать эту метку.

Comment: @Xander `данная метка нужна для вопросов о нюансах использования и реализации массивов` Вы это на ходу придумали? Только в названии вопроса слово массив присутствует два раза. А именно `как преобразовать массив в csv`. Я Вам еще раз повторяю что метки нужны для того что бы описать/классифицировать вопрос языком доступным машинам, что впоследствии поможет лучше структурировать данную базу знаний. Я крайне настоятельно рекомендую Вам перечитать правила использования меток и прекратить "вандализм" основанный на Вашем личном видение как именно их стоит использовать

Comment: для случая в вопросе достаточно: `[[1, 2], ['a', 'b']].join('\n')`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

```js
const array = [[1, 2], ["a", "b"]]

const temp = []

array.forEach((arr, i) => {
    const line = arr.join(",")
    temp.push(i === 0 ? `${line}\n` : line)
})

const result = temp.join("")

console.log(result)
// 1,2
// a,b

console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
// "1,2\na,b"
```

Отдельно добавляю способ, предложенный пользователем @Grundy, на случай, если перенос строки необходим *не только после первого массива*:

```js
const array = [[1, 2], ["a", "b"]]

const result = array.join("\n")

console.log(result)
// 1,2
// a,b

console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
// "1,2\na,b"
```

Comment: почему для вставки запятых между элементами используется `.join(',')` а для вставки `\n` странный цикл?

Comment: Жутко битый csv.

Answer (score 3):

Запятую, перевод строки и двойные кавычки надо эскейпить.

```js
const array = [
  [1, 2],
  [',,,"'],
  [',"",'],
  ['"""'],
  ['"'],
  ['a\nb'],
  ['ac']
];

function escapeCSV(val) {
  if (typeof val === 'string') {
    if (val.match(/(,|"|\n)/)) {
      val = val.replace(/"/g, '""');
      val = `"${val}"`;
    }
    return val;
  } else {
    return val;
  }
}

function getCSVFromArray(arr) {
  return arr.map((item, i) => {
    return item.map(m => escapeCSV(m)).join(",");
  }).join('\n');
}

console.log(getCSVFromArray(array));
```

Comment: Ну почти. Ещё надо заключать строку в кавычки если в ней есть перевод строки.

Comment: @Qwertiy спасибо, поправил. А сам перевод строки не надо эскейпить?

Comment: Вроде должно быть не надо. Хотя парсер может и накосячить... Кстати, а `\r` не надо?

Comment: @Qwertiy сложно сказать, я так близко с csv дела не имел, основывался на ответе из английского SO. Но там не было про экранирования переноса строки.